# send data in load data

Tags: javascript, php, post

Hı, 
I  have a script that loads my div tag some PHP files like this;

```
$(".loaddiv").click(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("id") + ".php";
  $("#orta_load").load(url);
  console.log("loading " + url);
});
```

when ı click a button; its load of some PHP files into `orta_load` div tag without refresh **(that is the problem)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="dahili" class="loaddiv"><span>Dahili Branşlar</span></a>
<a href="#" id="cerrahi" class="loaddiv"><span>Cerrahi Branşlar</span></a>
<div id="orta_load">
loading page
</div>
```

How can send data to another page which is upload?

for example, ı have a contact page that name is contact.php.
When I press submit button I should send all data to thanks.php page without refresh the main page

I tried lot of ways but I could not do this. when I press the button the page is refreshed or it is not send the data

What should I do?

Comment: You need event delegation. You should post the javascript that handles the form submit.

Comment: `that is the problem` So why do you use `load()` in the first place? Not clear what you want here. Use forms without javascript OR  use forms with javascript but use `ajax()` not `load()` and thing about the logic before you code anything

Comment: ı have a website and  the header and footer of the site always same. when ı click a link ı want to load the pages in just same tag which is name #ortaload

for example when ı click services link that in header area, the services.php page should load in #ortaload div.

ı do it with that code, but ı can't send data to another page which is loaded in #ortaload div 
 contact.php is loaded in #ortadiv. 
when ı click the submit button the datas should post to thank_you.php which is load in #ortaload tag. and thank_yoou.php should load in #ortaload div tag without refresh the main page